# Python TextBlob: Can't load classifer csv for training

Tags: python, csv, textblob

I'm trying to test out loading data from a csv file into TextBlob to create a classifier, which I'll then test with a training set. I've started with a small csv just to test it and ensure it works, before I write hundreds of lines for the real thing. However, I've run into an issue. I'm using the example code listed on the TextBlob website:

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier

with open('testerdict.csv',) as fp:
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")

test = [
    ('The beer was good.', 'pos'),
    ('I do not enjoy my job', 'neg'),
    ("I ain't feeling dandy today.", 'neg'),
    ("I feel amazing!", 'pos'),
    ('Gary is a friend of mine.', 'pos'),
    ("I can't believe I'm doing this.", 'neg')
]
cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp)
print(cl.classify("This is an amazing library!"))
print(cl.accuracy(test))
```

The errors I'm receiving vary depending on how I format my csv file, so I assume the issue lies there. If I format it like this:

!https://ibb.co/nx3ttx

I get this error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

If I format it like this:

!https://ibb.co/i6LHLc

I get this error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Like I said, I've just made a very quick and basic csv so I can understand how to properly format it and load it into TextBlob for training data for the classifier. Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: full traceback as requested:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\SA Project\Work\tester.py", line 14, in <module>
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp)
  File "C:\Users\Ver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 205, in __init__
    super(NLTKClassifier, self).__init__(train_set, feature_extractor, format, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.train_set = self._read_data(train_set, format)
  File "C:\Users\Ver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\textblob\classifiers.py", line 148, in _read_data
    format_class = formats.detect(dataset)
  File "C:\Users\Ver\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\textblob\formats.py", line 145, in detect
    if Format.detect(fp.read(max_read)):
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback for one of the approaches

Comment: Done as requested.

Comment: At a _guess_, indent `cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp)` to be in-line with `cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")`. EDIT: well actually it isn't as much of a guess as I first thought. `cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp)` is outside of the `with` block and its specific duty is to close files once you leave its scope.

Comment: Perhaps it might be of use if I included some demo code which functions correctly without loading the csv file? I'll put that in now, so that people can have an idea of the format required.

Comment: No, I think I already solved the issue. Did you try what I suggested? You'll also have to indent `test`

Comment: It works! Fantastic. Thank you very much. I can't believe I was having such a simple issue. I guess that's what happens when you try to use example code - you can overlook the small details and assume it's going to be correct. For anyone else who could have a similar issue, note that the first image uses the correct formatting. I've just tried it in the style of the second image and it won't work. Ensure you have two columns: one with the phrase, and one with a pos or neg label.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, with the second call to the NaiveBayesClassifier removed.  Is it necessary to call the constructor again?  Seems like it was already done inside the with statement:

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier

with open('<path to your file>.csv',) as fp:
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")

test = [('The beer was good.', 'pos'),
        ('I do not enjoy my job', 'neg'),
        ("I ain't feeling dandy today.", 'neg'),
        ("I feel amazing!", 'pos'),
        ('Gary is a friend of mine.', 'pos'),
        ("I can't believe I'm doing this.", 'neg')]
#cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp)
print(cl.classify("This is an amazing library!"))
print(cl.accuracy(test))
```

I used the CSV formatting described here:  http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html#classifying-text